# Getting CORS but I have it enabled

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuetify.js

My webapp it's working just fine until I got CORS error trying to do a request from a `v-autocomplete` (on a keydown event). Only happens me there and I don't know why. If I make the same request from any other place or any other component it works flawlessly. Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

sometimes the **CORS** headers are sent only on `OPTIONS` and `GET` , v-autocomplete might be a `PUT`

https://github.com/pelias/api/issues/296

Comment: hi, thanks for your response. I don't think that's the problem because it triggers an axios GET request.